Как получить доступ к определённому Navigation Bar, если их два в одном ViewController? Swift, UIKit
Так получилось, что в одном вью контроллере размещены два Navigation Bar. Один от Navigation Controller с общей навигацией, второй добавлен вручную для вставленной во вью контроллер TableView, чтобы можно было включать режим редактирования для таблицы.
Возможно ли в этом случае обращаться к определённому NavigationBar? Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку во втором Navigation Bar сам режим редактирования для таблицы включается нормально, т.е., видны иконки удаления ячейки и перетаскивания ячеек. При этом перетаскивание ячеек вверх-вниз работает, а удаление ячейки не работает.
Вот код для удаления ячейки, он стандартный, в других проектах нормально работает.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

Подозрение именно на то, что есть ещё один Navigation Bar, потому как пробовал разные варианты кода и случайно стало так, что в первом Navigation Bar стали меняться title для Bar Button Item.
Может кто сталкивался с таким, подскажите, please, как получить доступ к конкретному Navigation Bar? Пробовал через identifier, но что-то не реагирует.
